# How to reset arrow key orientation rotation by 90 degrees?

Tags: windows-7

Somehow the orientation of my arrow keys is rotated by 90 degrees. This means, when I press left, the cursor goes down, up is left, right is up and down is right. I tried to use another keyboard, but got the same issue.

Restart did fix the problem. But know I am curious. Did anybody experience a similar problem and knows how to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried fiddling around with any key mappings just before you started facing this issue?

Comment: No, it just happend. I thought, probably there is kind of a shortcut or something. But couldn't find any information.

Comment: Do any of your friends like to play practical jokes?

Comment: No, wasn't a joke. I did ask my colleagues

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, people's friends like to play [practical](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm) [jokes](http://www.instructables.com/id/Remapped-Keyboard-Prank/) on them.